# Custom Hook to Load Firebase Image URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to create a custom hook that will load the URL for an image stored in Firebase.

So far I've arrived at the following:

**useLoadImageURL.js**

```
export default async function useLoadImageURL(projectId, fileName) {
    const [url, setURL] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        return url
    }, [url])

    const storage = getStorage(app);
    setURL(await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `images/projects/${projectId}/${fileName}`)))
}
```

However, when I use it in my component, I only get promises, and therefore using the returned promise as URL does not work.

I'm calling the hook via the following:

**ProjectCard.js**

```
export default function ProjectCard({ project }) {
    const coverImageURL = useLoadImageURL(project.id, project.coverImagePath)
    return <img src={coverImageURL} />
}
```

How can I change the hook or how I'm calling it to retrieve the actual URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `async` and `await` from your code, and instead of calling `setUrl` at the bottom of your hook -- which would initiate the call every time the callee component rerenders -- wrap it in a `useEffect`, and update the state in a `then` callback.

edit: Full code:

```
const storage = getStorage(app); // as app seems to be external to the hook, storage can likely be too

export default function useLoadImageURL(projectId, fileName) {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `images/projects/${projectId}/${fileName}`))
      .then((value) => {
        setUrl(value); // should work provided getDownloadURL actually is a promise that gives a string
      });
  }, [projectId,fileName]);
  
  return url;
}
```

This will make the `url` state only change when `projectId` or `fileName` changes.

Comment: Are you intentionally calling a nested `getDownloadURL`? I wasn't aware that `getDownloadURL` can be passed as a parameter of itself. Also, when I run the new code, I get an error at the `getDownloadURL(getDownloadURL(...))` line saying `'Uncaught TypeError: ref._throwIfRoot is not a function`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. copy-pasted a bit to quickly there ;) I'll fix. Also added a crucial last paragraph.

Comment: So, the `ProjectCard` component still never receives the loaded URL. I can see that it receives an 'undefined' value at first while the hook has not yet fetched the URL, but once the URL state variable is fetched by the hook and returned, it is not updated in the `ProjectCard` component

Comment: I've changed the code to be a fully working hook. If it still doesn't work you could use `console.log` to see what `value` is in the `then` callback

Answer (score 1):

You have to do your side effect logic (awaiting async response in your case) inside the `useEffect` hook.

Following your intent to do it with promises and `async` `await`, your snippet hook should be something like this.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// hook
function useLoadImageURL(filename) {
  const [url, setURL] = useState("some-image-spinner-url");

  // simulating your async api call to firebase service
  const setTimeoutAsync = (cb, delay) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(cb());
      }, delay);
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncFn() {
      const url = await setTimeoutAsync(() => filename, 3000);
      setURL(url);
    }
    asyncFn();
  }, [filename]);

  return [url];
}

// main component
function App() {
  const [url] = useLoadImageURL("firebase-file-name-f1");
  return <div> {url} </div>;
}
export default App;
```